# React-router not displaying a functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have been trying to learn react-router, and was fiddling with it on stackBlitz, with the url [project link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mx1uvw)
The "About" content was displayed on the url but none of its content was being displayed.

The project is completely editable, can you please suggest me what could be the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your GetData.js line 34: remove `exact`

`exact` props mean that you want only `/:id`, not `/:id/about`

Comment: Thanks, was going nuts